# Changing access database connection string

Tags: c#, database, winforms

In my application i have a access database with a list of customers, this database is imported in my project. A combobox datasource is set to display all the customers.

I also created a form so the user can change some settings and locations of certain files. for this i use the `this.properties.settings.KlantenDB()` the string is created and will save the path to the customer database.

How can i change the current Access database connection string so it will use the KlantenDB path?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", path);
```

and provide the full path to the data files.

The `KlantenConnectionString` should provide the full connection string. That `|DataDirectory|` part of the connection string will be replaced with the value you set using the above call to `SetData`.

In your case, the following call should work

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", "C:");
```

Comment: This works great. Ended up with this. 
string klantenDBstring = Properties.Settings.Default.KlantenDB;
            int index = klantenDBstring.LastIndexOf(@"\");
            if (index > 0)
                klantenDBstring = klantenDBstring.Substring(0, index);
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", klantenDBstring);

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness: Never use something like `LastIndexOf` on path names. There's a `Path` class with methods you can use: `string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Properties.Settings.Default.KlantenDB);`